# Trying to alter already modified recovery partition on tablet

Tags: recovery-mode, 4.2-jelly-bean, tablet

I have an Android tablet (4.2.2) where the recovery has been modified to only give the reboot option when you boot into it. What is the best way to unlock the other options? Do I need to flash a new recovery partition? Or is there some way to open and edit the available options in the current one?

Comment: Your description sound more like the default recovery. Only custom recoveries like TWRP give more options. If the device is unlocked you can try to install a matching custom recovery that has more options.

Comment: The default is restricted. Most default recoveries give you more options than just reboot. They give you data wipe, cache wipe, flash update.zip, etc. I want to know how these options could have been disabled and how I can add them back. As in, what do I have to modify?

Comment: recovery options are hidden while bootloader is locked

Comment: So my focus should be on unlocking the bootloader then? That's how my recovery options were limited? So once I get the bootloader unlocked all recovery options will become available to me (without alteration of the recovery partition)? (Sorry for all the questions but I'm just making sure I understand your assertion)

Comment: can not 100% confirm but for some android system recovery there is hidden option backup user data. beware unlocking bootloader forces factory reset!