# Break or trivialize recovery mode

Tags: security, recovery-mode

Is it possible to have either a broken recovery mode (without bricking other modes) or a trivial recovery mode (e.g. no menu and automatically shutdown)? Where can I find existing ones or instructions to build my own one?

One naive "solution" I thought about is to flash 0 into /recovery, but I do not know if there may be unexpected consequences.

Comment: The main problem of flashing a broken recovery is that someone can reflash a working recovery using the same method. Therefore this only an obstacle for "very simple Android users".

Comment: @Robert I understand that. But exposing a 3-second factory reset option to everyone is even worse. Also, let's ignore FRP since that relies on google services.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is Android's system recovery a firmware thing or Android thing? Can factory reset be prevented?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/231977/is-androids-system-recovery-a-firmware-thing-or-android-thing-can-factory-rese)

Comment: @alecxs The answer in that question says " In A/B slots, recovery is part of boot.img so it can be directly booted by ABL." If I understand correctly normal boot and recovery do share the same kernel. But then where is the beginning of the railroad switch? in ramdisk?

Comment: that happens earlier. in ABL where the physical key is recognized.

Comment: @alecxs Ok key gets recognized. But suppose we are not on A-only device, the same kernel will be loaded. So there is going to be a firmware level railroad switch? Do recovery and normal os use the same ramdisk?

Comment: https://source.android.com/devices/bootloader/partitions/ramdisk-partitions

Comment: @alecxs No I am not mixing them up but that link clarifies a bit. Do we have control over kernel parameters or it is completely hardcoded in bootloader?

Comment: use this tool [AIK](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2073775) to separate ramdisk from kernel and have a look into *split_img/cmdline* txt file for parameters