# Where is Boot flow screen displayed in android

Tags: boot, bootloader, images

I have came across Boot flow and when there is based on boot state of a device, it shows different colot screen.

```
YELLOW: Warning screen for LOCKED devices with custom root of trust set
ORANGE: Warning screen for UNLOCKED devices
RED (eio): Warning screen for dm-verity corruption
RED (no os found): No valid OS found
```

Let me know where or from which path those screens are displaying?

Eg:[Yellow Screen](https://source.android.com/security/verifiedboot/boot-flow#locked-devices-with-custom-root-of-trust)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is Android's system recovery a firmware thing or Android thing? Can factory reset be prevented?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/231990)

Answer (score 4):

This is all happen in OEM bootloader (proprietary) before android is started. This screen is displayed before splash screen only in yellow/orange/red state

Comment: Let me know the path from aosp please. http://androidxref.com/9.0.0_r3/

Comment: @Abracadabra Bootloaders aren't part of AOSP. They are OEM-specific thing. AOSP contains just a  basic reference implementation of final bootloader (which loads kernel); check AVB documentation and code. Final bootloader in the device may or may not be based on it. It's entirely up to the OEM.

Comment: So correct me if I am wrong.  OEM specific will be available in device and not in aosp code?

Comment: @IrfanLatif then how it communicates with aosp and oem specific?

Comment: once chain of trust is broken android will not boot at all, that is what boot flow is designed for. are you mixing up with your other question *"how can i trace whether avb is running normally or not?"*

Comment: @alecxs no. Very simple. I just need to know from which path those different screens are displaying? Eg:  Orange Screen https://source.android.com/security/verifiedboot/boot-flow#unlocked-devices. In aosp souce code, which folder?

Comment: don't know what you mean. bootloader is proprietary. do you have source code of `aboot` or `lk` for your device?

Comment: no source code but usually where this will be available? @alecxs please let me know what is 1k or aboot. Sorry I am not aware of this.

Comment: @Abracadabra please spend time to learn the basics. It'll help you self answer many of your questions. You can start with https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/info-android-device-partitions-and-filesystems.3586565/ and https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/info-boot-process-android-vs-linux.3785254/ and https://android.stackexchange.com/a/220678/218526. Do check the AOSP links in the last link.

Comment: IrfanLatif has linked source code of [aboot](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/lk/+/refs/heads/master/app/aboot/aboot.c) but I am not even sure this is the stage where OEMs implement boot state warning screen. After reading source code I believe it is happen earlier in OEM bootloader which is what I should have called SBL (which is proprietary closed source). AVB/dm-verity on the other hand is implemented in aboot. google documentation is bit confusing because bootloader check (yellow screen) is actually predecessor to verifiedboot http://newandroidbook.com/Articles/aboot.html

Comment: for mediatek devices it is in [lk](https://www.lieberbiber.de/2015/07/05/mediatek-details-little-kernel) (little kernel, aka fastboot) which is bit different to qualcomm devices. XopmoH97 has written hex patch for disable yellow screen on mediatek devices [orange_state_disabler_v0.3.zip](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=ru&tl=en&u=https://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=942949%26view%3Dfindpost%26p%3D86260352)

Comment: I  analysed the hint message text of boot state warning screen in code but I am not able to find where those message comes from.

Comment: I am not able to download the zip. @alecxs