# Is the bootloader button sequence defined in the firmware?

Tags: bootloader, xiaomi

For a custom device that doesn't have the traditional phone buttons and no screen, is there a way to determine the button sequence to enter bootloader? I've seen the article howtogeek.com/249439/how-to-enter-androids-bootloader-and-recovery-environments/ which lists different manufacturers however I'm curious if there is a definition in the firmware itself.

For a small detail there are references that Xiaomi was used as the base for this custom firmware however since it's not a Xiaomi phone I don't want to button mash combinations and brick the device.

Comment: what device model?

Comment: @alecxs I'm not sure how to find that as it has no screen. Is it defined in the config or any files in the firmware then I can look it up for you. I got "OPM1.171019.026" from the build.prop.

Comment: getprop ro.build.fingerprint

Comment: @alecxs facebook/stella/stella:8.1.0/OPM1.171019.026

Comment: Oh, facebook builds hardware? what is it, a watch, vr glasses, tv stick? so the model name is "facebook" and codename is "stella" - could not find anything useful

Comment: A rayban glasses device. It's okay, you wouldn't find anything online about it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: It's probably of no use to enter bootloader as there is no usb to interact with. However universal method always is *'reboot bootloader'* from adb or terminal. boot mode is determinated in bootloader aboot or lk little kernel (see comments [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/241421) or this [blog](https://ge0n0sis.github.io/posts/2016/05/how-to-lock-the-samsung-download-mode-using-an-undocumented-feature-of-aboot))